# jQuery: Sum of all data appended with specific date

Tags: jquery, json, sum

I retrieve some data off an API and I append it as such:

```
if (jsontext == '[]') {
    return false
} else {

    var newTr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        newTr += (' / ' + json[i].date + ' ' + json[i].price);

    }

    console.log(newTr);

}
```

which gives me a huge list of results as such:

*/ 07-09-2012 72.60 / 11-09-2012 194.98 / 03-09-2012 94.82 / 04-09-2012 187.56 / 31-10-2012 72 / 18-09-2012 204.75 / 26-09-2012 243.73 / 14-09-2012 86.40 / 20-09-2012 91.63 / 28-09-2012 96.56 / 01-09-2012 94.62 / 17-09-2012 94.86 / 17-09-2012 83.25 / 12-09-2012 94.85 / 18-09-2012 94.86 / 18-09-2012 68.74 / 21-09-2012 94.86 / 21-09-2012 94.86 / 24-09-2012 144.23 / 28-09-2012 92.77 / 30-09-2012 92.77 / 28-09-2012 92.77 / 13-09-2012 151.12 / 03-09-2012 125.80 / 05-09-2012 92.61 / 05-09-2012 95.54 / 12-09-2012 94.59 / 12-09-2012 94.59 / 13-09-2012 125.83 / 18-09-2012 109.38*

and keep's going.

How can I take the sum of the pricing for the month 09?

**The date format is dd-mm-yyyy**.

Comment: Do you need the console output parsed? Or why don't you just use the `json` array you already have?

Comment: @jQuerybeast, just because of curiosity: Why does this question say current ansewers do not contain enough details? Have you reviewed my answer below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that what you have is a string like below,

```
"/ 07-09-2012 72.60 / 11-09-2012 194.98 / 03-09-2012 94.82 / 04-09-2012 187.56 / 31-10-2012 72 / 18-09-2012 204.75 / 26-09-2012 243.73 / 14-09-2012 86.40 / 20-09-2012 91.63 / 28-09-2012 96.56 / 01-09-2012 94.62 / 17-09-2012 94.86 / 17-09-2012 83.25 / 12-09-2012 94.85 / 18-09-2012 94.86 / 18-09-2012 68.74 / 21-09-2012 94.86 / 21-09-2012 94.86 / 24-09-2012 144.23 / 28-09-2012 92.77 / 30-09-2012 92.77 / 28-09-2012 92.77 / 13-09-2012 151.12 / 03-09-2012 125.80 / 05-09-2012 92.61 / 05-09-2012 95.54 / 12-09-2012 94.59 / 12-09-2012 94.59 / 13-09-2012 125.83 / 18-09-2012 109.38"
```

If that is the case then you need to parse the string to calculate the sum by month.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/pBNNt/

**Full Code:**

```
var resultArr = result.split('/');
var results = {}; //sum by month
for (var i = 0; i < resultArr.length; i++) {    
    if ( resultArr[i].length >= 11) { //it has date
        var resultTkn = resultArr[i].split(' ');

        if (resultTkn[1].length == 10) { //it is a date
            var date = resultTkn[1].split('-');
            var sum = 0;
            if (results.hasOwnProperty(date[1])) {
                sum = results[date[1]];
            }

            sum += parseFloat(resultTkn[2]);
            results[date[1]] = sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can access the sum by month using the results objects. `results["09"]` returned `3305.93`

Comment: For some reason result["09"] returns undefined

Comment: @jQuerybeast Did the demo worked for you? I tried in all browsers and it all rendered the same.. Let me know..

Comment: I've literally pasted the entire text I receive and I get undefined result on your example aswell: http://jsfiddle.net/javascript/pBNNt/3/

Comment: Somewhere im the results I parse, there's an empty price? not sure

Comment: Found it: There are some areas that I get /  0 /

Comment: @jQuerybeast You made a typo in that `console.log(result["09"])`. It should be `console.log(results["09"]);` DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pBNNt/4/

Comment: I've deleted all the / 0 / from my database, as those were there by mistake from my accountant I suppose, but again with the new results it returns undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/javascript/pBNNt/5/

Comment: @jQuerybeast  `resultArr[i].length >= 11` would check for any `data > 11` characters which would ignore those `/ 0 /` entries. Additionally I would suggest adding `NaN` check on those numbers before adding it up.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I've tried to explain this as clear as I can based on the comments:

Firstly, you need to add function, which is responsible for parsing your date string (the `input` parameter in format dd-mm-yyyy), and returns the proper date object:

```
// parse a date in dd-mm-yyyy
function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
    // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]); // months are 0-based
}
```

After that write function, which does what you've asked about - returns the sum of prices for provided month:

```
// get sum of prices for given month
function getSumForMonth(data, month) {
    var sum = 0;
    month -= 1; // months are 0-based 
    $.each(data, function (idx, item) {
        if (parseDate(item.date).getMonth() == month) {
            sum += parseFloat(item.price);
        }
    });
    return sum;
}
```

To get what you want you have to invoke function defined above. The `data` parameter is your json variable, and `month` parameter is the index of the month you want to get the result for:

```
var sum = getSumForMonth(json, 9); // sum for september
console.log(sum);
```

EDIT 2: Protection in case of null items in deserialized json object...

```
$.each(data, function(idx, item) {
    if (item != null && item.date != null && item.price != null) {
        if (parseDate(item.date).getMonth() == month) {
            sum += parseFloat(item.price);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: and how can I get the sum of the month 08 with this? and where should I place this? I think its not very clear.

Comment: I've wrapped the logic with a function, which takes the month index and returns the sum of prices - it should be pretty straightforward now.

Comment: Your answer is not clear sir. Where does it get the input? Can you please check my question's javascript and explain me where I would apply your snippet? It seems that Many variables are not declared

Comment: Hey, just check the edit, I hope my explanation helps - if not, I have to give up ;]

Comment: Hey, I've understood your answer but where ever I place it your snippet, i get errors. Im not sure where it has to be placed. That's what i would like you to show me. Here is how it looks now: http://pastebin.com/DSREMHRV  I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null on the line: return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);

Comment: If you're asking questions connected to the topics you don't understand, try to learn the basics firstly. Here is how it should look: http://pastebin.com/1SvvhNeR

Comment: I tend to learn once I have the answer. I do a reverse engineering. I guess everyone has a different approach to learning. Anyhow, you're answer returns an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null on the line: return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);

Comment: The error rises because somewhere in your json data, `date` object is null, so the expression which throws an error can't find length of that, because it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// declare before looping through your JSON
var sums = [];

...
newTr += (' / ' + json[i].date + ' ' + json[i].price);
...

// month-year
var mY = json[i].date.split('-');

/* EDIT: changed my to mY */
mY = mY[1] + '-' + mY[2];


// this will give you an array with sums for each month
sums[mY] == undefined ? sums[mY] = parseFloat(json[i].price) : sums[mY] += parseFloat(json[i].price);
```

Comment: and how can I get the sum of the month 09 with this?

Comment: You can add a console.log(sums) to see the array contents. The sum you need should be `sums['09-2012']`

Comment: but where do I add this? after the closing bracket?

Comment: when i set a specific date, I get undefined. If I console.log(sums), I get 04,02,2012: 287, 18,02,2012: 149, 19,10,2012: 1028, 15,05,2012: 1514, 23,01,2012: 32139, 03,02,2012: 1442, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick snippet:

```
    var string_array = yourStringLine.split("/");
    var length = string_array.length;
    var sum = 0;
    for(var y = 0; y < length; y++) {
       var date_data = string_array[y].split(" ");
       var month = date_data[0].split("-")[1];
       if(month == "09") {
            sum += parseFloat(date_data[1]);
       }
    }
```

It's pretty ugly but i think you can get the idea. It's simple string parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, and I would think obvious one, is to use Regular Expressions.

This function will do the test:

```
function forGivenMonth(month, input){
    var custom_regex = "[0-9]{2}-" + month + "-[0-9]{4}"
    var regex = new RegExp(custom_regex);
    if(regex.test(input)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

And then in your existing code:

```
if (jsontext == '[]') {
    return false
} else {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        if(forGivenMonth("09", json[i].date){
            sum += json[i].price;
        }
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

You can keep replacing the `"09"` in the function call with different months.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say its better to avoid string splitting as it will perform badly, and go for a regular expression based solution. While there are such answers already, I think there is a better way to do that (as always, there could be better ways than this too)

Here I've written a function which can accept source, month and year and return the sum. I've avoided using split functions.

```
   function(source, month, year) {
        var rexp = new RegExp("/\\s+\\d{2}-" + month + "-" + year + "\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+", "g");

        var tot = 0;
        var m = rexp.exec(source);
        while (m) {
            var n = new Number(m[1]);
            tot += (n || 0.0)
            // This is only for debugging purposes
            $("#container").append($('<span>').text(" Found match : " + m[0] + ", Number => " + m[1] + ", Total => " + tot.toString())).append($('<br />'));

            m = rexp.exec(source);
        }

        return tot;
    }
```

For the full solution check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BuddhiP/NUmf4/)

Answer (score 0):

This is just techfoobar solution, so he deserves the credit. It didn't work just because of a typo (my instead of mY). This is the full listing, applied to your problem.

Please note that this (=his) is a much better solution than the accepted one, as the sums are created while parsing the json and not by splitting it again (read all json, merge it in one var, split it again to calculate the sums is all useless work).

```
var sums = [];

if (jsontext == '[]') {
    return false
} else {

    var mY;
    var newTr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        newTr += (' / ' + json[i].date + ' ' + json[i].price);
        mY = json[i].date.split('-');
        mY = mY[1] + '-' + mY[2];
        sums[mY] == undefined ? sums[mY] = parseFloat(json[i].price) : sums[mY] += parseFloat(json[i].price);
    }

    console.log(newTr);

}

function getMonthSum(y,m) {
    return sums[y+"-"+m];
}

alert(getMonthSum("2012","09"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Testing Setup
var jsontext;
var json = [
    { date:"07-09-2012", price:"72.60"},
    { date:"11-09-2012", price:"194.98"},
    { date:"03-09-2012", price:"94.82"},
    { date:"04-09-2012", price:"187.560"},
    { date:"31-10-2012", price:"72"},
    { date:"18-09-2012", price:"204.75"},
    { date:"26-09-2012", price:"243.73"},
    { date:"14-09-2012", price:"86.40"},
    { date:"20-09-2012", price:"91.63"},
    { date:"28-09-2012", price:"96.56"},
    { date:"01-09-2012", price:"94.62"},
    { date:"17-09-2012", price:"94.86"},
    { date:"17-09-2012", price:"83.25"},
    { date:"12-09-2012", price:"94.85"},
    { date:"18-09-2012", price:"94.86"},
    { date:"18-09-2012", price:"68.74"},
    { date:"21-09-2012", price:"94.86"},
    { date:"21-09-2012", price:"94.86"},
    { date:"24-09-2012", price:"144.23"},
    { date:"28-09-2012", price:"92.77"},
    { date:"30-09-2012", price:"92.77"},
    { date:"28-09-2012", price:"92.77"},
    { date:"13-09-2012", price:"151.12"},
    { date:"03-09-2012", price:"125.80"},
    { date:"05-09-2012", price:"92.61"},
    { date:"05-09-2012", price:"95.54"},
    { date:"12-09-2012", price:"94.59"},
    { date:"12-09-2012", price:"94.59"},
    { date:"13-09-2012", price:"125.83"},
    { date:"18-09-2012", price:"109.38"}
];

//  New function
//
function sum( month, data ) {
    var sum = 0;
    $.each( data,function(i,val){
        var parts = val.date.split("-");
        if( parts.length==3 && parseInt(parts[1])==month ) {
            sum += parseFloat("0"+val.price);
        }
    });
    return sum;
}


// Your Code
//
if (jsontext == '[]') {
    return false
} else {

    var newTr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        newTr += (' / ' + json[i].date + ' ' + json[i].price);

    }
    console.log(newTr);

    // !!!  THE CALL TO MY CODE !!!!
    console.log(sum(9,json));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

if (jsontext == '[]') {
    return false
} else {

```
var newTr = '';
var newmonth=0'';
var sum=0;  
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    newTr += (' / ' + json[i].date + ' ' + json[i].price);

newmonth=parseDate(json[i].date).getMonth();
if (parseDate(json[i].date).getMonth() <> newmonth)
{
  newmonth=parseDate(json[i].date).getMonth();
  newTr += (' / '+'Total for month '+ newmonth +' :'+sum);
  sum = 0;
}
    else
{
   sum+= parseFloat(json[i].price);
}

}

console.log(newTr);
```

}

function parseDate(input) {

```
var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
// new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]); // months are 0-based
```

}

Comment: Totally wrong. Your code is so messed up, returns so many errors